# php get data from mysql by date

Tags: php, mysql, date

if i have data in mysql like this

```
----------------------------------
id - title - date
1  - samy  - 2017-08-03 10:38:58 AM
2  - sara  - 2017-08-03 05:38:58 AM
3  - susan -2017-08-04 04:38:58 AM
-----------------------------------
```

using php how can i call what data between 05:00 am at 03-08-2017 and 05:00 am at 04-08-2017 
i used

```
$sql = "select id,title,date from orders 
where Day(date)='03' AND Month(date)='08' AND Year(date)='2017'";
```

but it's only display all data in 03-08-2017
i also need to get data in 04-08-2017 from 12:00 am to 05:00 am just all data added in those five hours and if i used

```
$sql = "select id,title,date from orders 
where Day(date)='04' AND Month(date)='08' AND Year(date)='2017'";
```

i need to hide all data added between 12:00 am To 05:am in that day and get data between 12:00 am and 05:am in the next day
how can i do that ?

Comment: what is your datatype in table for column `date` ?

Comment: yes it's datetime

Comment: Then how can you store dates with `am` and `pm` in mysql datetime?

Comment: i didn't i just wrote them above to clear my point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT id,title,date FROM orders WHERE date BETWEEN '2017-08-03 05:00:00' AND '2017-08-04 05:00:00'"
```

That should get you in the right place. Now if you want to automate that with php, you could set the string using variables and update the day using a function when it is time to do it the next day.

Comment: i'm using my sql above in search filter and between not working with months or years

Comment: Something is wrong somewhere else then. Either maybe old old version of MySQL and syntax has changed, or outdated php, but my snippet works, just tried it.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d3f4/1/0

Answer (score 0):

You need to simply use `between` to get data between two dates. Change your query to

```
$sql = "SELECT id,title,date FROM orders
        WHERE date BETWEEN '2017-08-03 05:00:00' AND '2017-08-04 05:00:00'";
```